# A constant number of calories burnt for an exercise lasting different durations

Tags: energy, work, power

So in the gym, me and a friend doing 2000 m on the rowing machine burnt the same amount of calories, but I did the exercise in 14 mins and he did it in 10 mins. Given that both of us have similar body types and weigh approximately the same. How is this possible?

I realise that the time difference is only 4 minutes, but surely as there is more power generated in the 10 mins compared to the 14 mins, there should be a difference in calories burnt?

Thanks for any answers (this question might not be completely relevant to this site, but I appreciate any guidance).

Comment: There certainly should be. Looks like the machine is only taking into account the number of strokes.

Comment: Maybe you both did the same work, but you used a higher power (?)